# Preparing data for a form view (django, drf, axios, vuejs)

Tags: django, vue.js, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm building a web application with Django, DRF, Axios and Vuejs.
It works but I'm wondering what are best practices for handling such a case.
Considering the form below :

[image: form view screenshot]

I want to create an Item for which I can assign a Company and a Contact.
The Company is a model in its own as well as the Contact. The Contact field shows only contacts for the selected Company.

How should I query the datas to be the most RESTful possible ?

1. Query all the companies, query all the contacts, and make a computed property that shows only contacts of the currently selected company ?
2. Query all the companies, and each time I select a company I query related Contacts only ?
3. Other solution ?

Both have pros and cons and I wonder what is the best way to handle this kind of situation. Also, if there are standard ways to design this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the GET API for all the 'Companies', then when the user selects a company, call the GET API for the 'Contacts'. That is how its usually done in enterprise applications, for e.g: when you select a country and then a city.

But you have to weigh the pros and cons of each method. Think about the distant future of your application. If you scale/expand, will the number of companies and the related contacts increase? Then it will be efficient to fetch the contacts only when the user selects a company. If not, and you know the maximum number of companies and their subsequent contacts, and you know that the number is small enough to load beforehand, than go with loading everything as soon as the form loads.